# In a c++ iterator, should I define both operator== and operator!=?

Tags: c++, iterator, operator-overloading

When I write an iterator for a custom container,
should I define both `operator==` and `operator!=`?

Initially I thought that I should define both, but then I read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator), in the table of expressions that have to be defined, that only `i != j` has to be defined. Though, it says that it should be equivalent to `!(i==j)`, so I am not sure whether the latter should be defined or not.

In clang++-5.0, range-based for-loops work well as long as I define `!=`.

In case it is required to define `operator==` too, the next question is: why? Why not just require one of them and calculate the other automatically?

Comment: What kind of iterator do you want?  There are input, output, forward, bidirectional, and random access.

Comment: @NathanOliver I want an iterator that I can use in range-based for loops. Is it called a "forward iterator"?

Comment: Depending on what you want, an input iterator would be okay to use.   [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) is a really good page that can help you pick which iterator type you want to implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr: Yes, you *should*, though for just range-based `for` you may not *need* to.**

---

Assuming from your link that you want to create a *InputIterator*:

> Initially I thought that I should define both, but then I read here, in the table of expressions that have to be defined, that only `i != j` has to be defined. Though, it says that it should be equivalent to `!(i==j)`, so I am not sure whether the latter should be defined or not.

Yes, it should. That requirement comes from *EqualityComparable*, which is also mentioned on that page (but not enumerated in the table, which does not define "inherited" requirements, or requirements that already fall into a category used elsewhere in the language).

An *InputIterator* may not be what you want; you can use the table on [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) to decide. But, at first glance, they *all* ultimately require *EqualityComparable* in the same way.

Range-based for is not specified in terms of iterator categories, but [it needs `++`, `!=` and `*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for); the tightest match for this set of requirements is *InputIterator*.

As for *why* `!=` is required as well as `==`, well, it would be possible for the standard library to use `!(x == y)` everywhere, but then if you *wanted* to provide some `!=` that was somehow cheaper then it would go unused, which would be annoying. This way, if all it does is `!(x == y)`, it takes seconds to define that and doesn't cost you anything.

Comment: It's weird thast it is not in the table since it is the first iterator that requires EqulityComparable.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think it's just a way of de-duping the definition of _EqualityComparable_ (which is also required elsewhere), but I agree that presenting the facts in a standardese manner on a wiki is perhaps not the clearest approach.

Comment: Thanks for the note on the inheritance from EqualityComparable; I did not notice this. But I still do not understand - if all I need is range-based for loops, and these loops, by the standard, do not use ==, then why do I need to define ==?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi: You don't. You asked whether you _should_, and I explained what you must do in order to satisfy various requirements. range-based for will only use `++`, `!=` and `*` if it abides strictly by the standard's definition. However by the as-if rule (and noting the minimum requirements on iterators, as described above), it's conceivable that in practice you may need more. I'd just implement the iterator to match one of the standard categories then you're safe

Answer (score 2):

> Why not just require one of them and calculate the other automatically?

Because you may want to customise it for speed *etc*.

Comment: We will, when we get the spaceship operator, `<=>`, in C++20: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons

Comment: @Ben: At least now [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1185r2.html#why-this-is-really-bad) has been accepted, yes!